# what does "<()" mean in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm trying to install RVM. There is a magical command line:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
```

I know what bash and curl are. I know the first `<` is the I/O redirection. But what does `<()` syntax mean?

What's the difference between this command and

```
bash < `curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm`
```

?(the latter command doesn't work)

Comment: I have no idea, but it looks like a penguin!

Comment: In your second example your command expand to a string which bash and try to connect it to the input stream of your process. Try `cat < somefile` to understand and `cat < <(echo test)`. It probably tells that `X file does not exists`.

Comment: @tomasz: just what I was thinking (")>

Comment: Be aware that if you use this syntax it may leave a named pipe in your /tmp/ directory; even after the process terminates.  Therefore you will also need some scheme to cleanup your /tmp/ directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is bash's [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

The expression `<(list)` gets replaced by a file name, either a named FIFO or an entry under `/dev/fd`.  So to actually redirect input from it, you have to use `< <(list)`.

[edit; forgot to answer your second question]

The backticks are called ["command substitution"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03).  Unlike process substitution, it is part of the POSIX shell specification (i.e., not a bash extension).  The shell runs the command in the backticks and substitutes its output on the command line.  So this would make sense:

```
cat < `echo /etc/termcap`
```

But this would not:

```
cat < `cat /etc/termcap`
```

The latter is similar to your example; it tries to use the (complex) output of a command as a file name from which to redirect standard input.

Answer (score 7):

The others have already answered your question very nicely. I'll just add an example to build on them... 99% of the time when I personally use `<()`, it's to diff the output of two different commands in one shot. For instance,

`diff <( some_command ) <( some_other_command )`

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for io redirection is

```
process < file
```

Hence you need whatever appears after the io redirect to be a filename.

The backtick expansion literally puts the results of the command into the command line.  Thus,

```
 `curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm`
```

expands to something like
     #!/usr/bin/env bash ...

and the shell would be confused because it would see

```
 bash < #...
```

instead of a filename.

the `<()` operator is process substitution, which spawns a new process to run the command within the (..).  A new file or pipe is created that will capture the result.  The fact that the arrow is pointing left `<()` instead of `>()` means that the output from the inner process will be written to the file, which can be read by the process.

In your case, `bash < <(...)` will be seen as something like `bash < /dev/fd/100`

If you actually want to see what is going on, run

```
echo <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).